# Arduino 3rd party cores

Tags: arduino-ide

I am trying to use Arduino platform.txt to run some extra pre-processing on my Arduino codes.

As far as I can understand the best way to do that is to use prebuild hooks as mentioned below
https://github.com/arduino/arduino/wiki/arduino-ide-1.5-3rd-party-hardware-specification

I am using the hooks as follows

```
recipe.hooks.sketch.prebuild.1.pattern=echo {source_file} sketch pret;
recipe.hooks.sketch.prebuild.2.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.c.cmd}" {compiler.c.flags} -mmcu={build.mcu} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.c.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"
```

This is the output I get for the hooks

```
echo "{source_file}" sketch pret;
{source_file} sketch pret;
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10804 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"
avr-gcc: error: {includes}: No such file or directory
avr-gcc: error: {source_file}: No such file or directory
avr-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

The {source_file} variable is used in a compilation reciep as follows

```
recipe.cpp.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.cpp.cmd}" {compiler.cpp.flags} -mmcu={build.mcu} -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.cpp.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"
```

and the recipe runs as follows

```
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10804 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/vinayakjoshi/Library/Arduino15/packages/boltiot/hardware/avr/1.0.0/variants/boltduino" "-I/Users/vinayakjoshi/Documents/Arduino/libraries/boltiot-arduino-helper-update-dev/src" "-I/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src" "/var/folders/kp/9gnp402j7_nfb1qpqpdkxgcr0000gn/T/arduino_build_658970/sketch/CommandHandler.ino.cpp" -o "/var/folders/kp/9gnp402j7_nfb1qpqpdkxgcr0000gn/T/arduino_build_658970/sketch/CommandHandler.ino.cpp.o"
```

As you can see, in a standard recipe, the variable {source_file} and other such definitions are correctly replaced. But in the hooks, this is not happening.

I want to know whether it is possible to get the value of the {source_file} variable to be used with the hooks, so that I can do some extra pre-processing with it. And if it is, how can I do it.

P.S. IDK what tag has to be used. I couldn't find platform.txt or 3rd party cores. I used the Arduino-IDE tag, as this question definitely asks how the IDE works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like those properties are only expanded in:

- `recipe.cpp.o.pattern`
- `recipe.S.o.pattern`
- `recipe.c.o.pattern`
- `recipe.preproc.includes`
- `recipe.preproc.macros`

They are not expanded in any of the hook recipes.

This actually makes sense for `{source_file}` with the current build system because the hooks are not run before and after the compilation of each file but rather before and after the entire sketch compilation, so even if that property was expanded it could only give you an arbitrary filename, perhaps the first file to be compiled in the prebuild hook and the last in the postbuild hook, but that leaves all the other filenames inaccessible so it really wouldn't do much good. See [related issue report](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/7160).

If you're actually trying to use `{source_file}` to get the preprocessed sketch file, that's accessible from any recipe as `{build.path}/sketch/{build.project_name}.cpp`.

As for `{includes}`, it seems like an unnecessary restriction for that property to only expand in specific recipes. If you can present a good case for this behavior being changed, it might be worth opening a feature request to see what the Arduino developers will think.